# IIS hanging website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET website that gets into a hanging state randomly. Sometimes it will return non-.net files like css/js. Other times it wont response to any request. When it is in the state, it is gone and can only be recovered with an IISRESET. Odd thing is when I perform the IISRESET, it fails. I always have to run it a 2nd time to get the site to recycle.

I have IIS tracing turned on with a time limit of 10 seconds. But this only creates logs when the site is running normal and a request takes longer than 10 seconds. But when it is in this hung state, no trace request logs are recorded at all.

I have used process monitor looking for access denied file request. But there are none and that makes sense. File access errors are usually not random.

I am at a loss on how to diagnose this issue. I am going to take a mem dumb of the w3wp and analyze it with WinDebug, but I am not sure if that will give me any good intel on the culprit.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Below is the list of requests. You can see the length of time and how that are in `stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core`.

> C:\Windows\system32>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests /elapsed:30000
>
> REQUEST "fe00000280000147" (url:GET /, time:548687 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)
>
> REQUEST "d5000002800007da" (url:GET /_DEV/TdsService.asmx, time:496609 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)
>
> REQUEST "c4000000800001c9" (url:GET /, time:471609 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)
>
> REQUEST "df00000180000012" (url:GET /, time:431281 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)
>
> REQUEST "ff00000180000252" (url:GET /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx?ts=3200641, time:385422 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)
>
> REQUEST "e500000180000060" (url:GET /default.css, time:289406 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)
>
> REQUEST "c10000008000029c" (url:GET /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx?ts=8571320, time:196281 msec, client:127.0.0.1, stage:BeginRequest, module:IIS Web Core)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Just starting to get the same symptom here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug diag is your friend here.Launch a debug diag when the hang happens and capture trace or you can set debug diag to capture trace automatically

Tess Fernandez has labs here to help here :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-lab-1-hang/